# Is it possible to swap out the v6 in my 2019 Ford f 150 XL rwd with a 4.6 v8 2 valve engine?

Tags: engine, ford, truck

Can I swap out the v6 in my 2019 Ford f150 xl regular cab to a 4.6 v8 2 valve engine? Will the wiring, plumbing,drive train and exhaust be needed to changed as well? And if so what kind of the wiring, plumbing, drive train and exhaust be needed in order for the swap to work perfectly?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How deep is your pocket book? It's a given, enough money can solve *any* swap issues.

Comment: It _can_ be done, but most of the components you listed will either need to be modified or replaced. It would probably be a more economical choice to simply sell the v6 truck and buy a v8 one.

Comment: Yes, I am sure it COULD be done.  Should it be done is an entirely different question.  A 2019 is pretty new, you might consider just selling it and using the proceeds to but another F150 with the V8 engine.  I am sure that would be the less expensive option.

Comment: If you're talking about swapping your brand new V6 for an old modular V8 then you'd need to be aware the V6 has superior horsepower and torque. The old modular V8 has 292HP and 320LB-FT, the new V6 has 325HP and 400LB-FT. You'd be spending a lot of money to **downgrade** your engine!